# Creating a calendar day view

Tags: swiftui

I'm looking to draw a classic calendar day view from a specific Date as argument. Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarDayView: View {
    
    var day = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // day of the week
            Text(day,
                 format: Date.FormatStyle().weekday(.wide))
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            .background(.red)
            .clipShape(.rect)
            
            // day number in month
            Text(day,
                 format: Date.FormatStyle().weekday(.twoDigits))
            .font(.title)
            .clipShape(.rect)
            .foregroundStyle(.red)
            .background(.primary)
            
            // Month and Year
            HStack {
                // Month
                Text(day,
                     format: Date.FormatStyle().month(.wide))
                
                // Year
                Text(day,
                     format: Date.FormatStyle().year(.twoDigits))
                
            }   .font(.caption)
            .clipShape(.rect)
            .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            .background(.red)
        }
        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
    }
}
```

I'm not far from the desired result:

[image]

My problem is about frame with the red and the white rectangles. I'm looking to something more like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full width you have to specify `.frame(maxWidth:` with value `infinity`.

> something more like this

is

```
struct CalendarDayView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("Monday")
                .padding(4)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red.gradient)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text("August")
                .font(.caption)
            Text("21")
                .font(.largeTitle).fontWeight(.medium)
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
        
    }
}
```